# How to restore login data from a backup user-data folder to a fresh install of Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, restore, chromium, microsoft-edge

I am trying to restore all my settings from a backup `user-data` folder to a freshly installed edge Chromium-based browser.

I do not want to restore the whole folder, just the main data.

I was able to restore the history, search engine, settings and my extensions (including the locals one and their data) and so on, but not my login data.

If I copy/paste the file "Login Data" from by backup to the default folder, and then open Edge, I am not logged in the websites I need. I know the needed data are somewhere in my backup user-data folder, because if I restore it in full, I am logged in the websites I need. So which files/folder should I copy from my backup user-data folder to my freshly installed user-data folder to get my login data back?

---

- **Folders I have already restored from my backup**: Web Data, Application Cache, Cache, Extension Rules, Extension State, Extensions, Local App Settings, Local Extension Settings, Local Storage, Managed Extension Settings, Sessions, Sync App Settings, Sync Extension Settings
- **Files I have already restored from my backup**: Bookmarks, Cookies, Extension Cookies, History, Last App Session, Login Data, Preferences, Secure Preferences